# Bank deposit needed show to apply for study permit in Canada

Tags: canada, study

Do I need to show bank deposit to the visa-office if I have secured TA or RA as a PhD student (i.e. I have means to pay off my living cost) in a Canadian university?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what [Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-how-documents.asp) says:

> 3. Proof of financial support
>
> You must prove that you can support yourself and the family members
>   who accompany you while you are in Canada. You can prove that you have
>   sufficient funds to support yourself in Canada by showing some of the
>   following:
>
> - proof of a Canadian bank account in your name if money has been transferred to Canada;
> - proof of a student/education loan from a financial institution;
> - your bank statements for the past four months;
> - a bank draft in convertible currency;
> - proof of payment of tuition and accommodation fees;
> - a letter from the person or institution providing you with money;
> - proof of funding paid from within Canada if you have a scholarship or are in a Canadian-funded educational program.

Edit: The list above had an 'and' in the next to last option. This is misleading as any or all of these options are acceptable. You could have a mix of cash, loan proceeds, scholarships, etc.

Comment: But, does this include TA/RA facility?

Comment: Note the last bullet point.